# Problemas com resultados de entrada depois de usar um "int()"

Tags: python, input, conversão-de-tipo, int

Exemplo de código:

```
idade = input("Qual a sua idade? ")    
int(idade)

if idade >= 45:    
    print("Tá velho cara, já era!")    
else:    
    print("A vida está só começando rapaz!")
```

Erro encontrado:

> ```
> Qual a sua idade? 45
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Lucio/Desktop/ProgramasPython.py", line 6, in <module>
>     if idade >= 45:
> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
> ```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Na segunda linha você está convertendo o conteúdo da variável `idade` para inteiro e descartando o resultado, aí quando vai verificar acha que já é um inteiro, mas ainda é uma *string*. Imagino que queria guardar isso em algum lugar. E imagino que acha que só fazendo a operação na variável muda o valor dela, mas isto não acontece, você apenas manipula o valor dela.

Mas o mais correto seria criar outra variável já que são tipos diferentes. E o erro causado mostra porque é melhor não reaproveitar variável com tipos diferentes. Em Python funcionaria jogar na mesma variável, mas não é legal fazer isto. A parte boa é que nem precisa fazer isso, pode ler o dado e converter de uma vez só e só guardar o valor convertido, assim:

```
idade = int(input("Qual a sua idade? "))
if idade >= 45:
    print("Tá velho cara, já era!")
else:
    print("A vida está só começando rapaz!")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZGzdPC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lywnnfhp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Age.py).

Esse código ainda pode falhar, pode ser escrito de outra forma, mas basicamente, pra começar aprender, é isto.

Answer (score 2):

Você pensou que `int(idade)` transformaria a variável `idade` em um inteiro, confere?

Pois bem, você acabou de ver que não foi isso o que aconteceu. O construtor `int(str)` quando recebe uma string cria um objeto do tipo `int` cujo valor em decimal é aquele que seria mostrado na string. Isso de fato foi feito no seu código. Porém, sem apontá-lo em nenhuma variável, esse objeto será criado e perdido. Para não perder, você precisa atribuir esse valor a uma variável. Então, você poderia até fazer:

```
idade = input("Qual a sua idade? ")    
idade = int(idade)
```

Mas, na real? Você quer ler um número inteiro, então por que não ler já um inteiro? Fica assim:

```
idade = int(input("Qual a sua idade? "))
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Esse erro acontece devido ao fato de estar sendo utilizado o operador relacional (>=), entre a string e o inteiro.

Para corrigir basta adicionar aspas duplas no inteiro ("45") conforme exemplo abaixo:

idade = input("Qual a sua idade? ")
int(idade)

if idade >= "45":
    print("Tá velho cara, já era!")
else:
    print("A vida está só começando rapaz!")